# designing android ui in java instead of xml?

Tags: java, android, user-interface

anyone know some good guides for this? there seems to be almost nothing out there. the best I've found is [this](http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/48845.aspx) but it isn't very comprehensive.

also, I'm really new to android development. I know there are resources like the [api](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) out there but I'm looking for more of a guide, and doing the ui in java just seemed more appealing than xml.

Comment: Well if you noticed majority of the properties which you set programatically have very similar or the same name to the XML UI.. I'd say that you need to understand how XML UI is being constructed anyways.

Comment: for a guide, besides the API reference there's the whole Android Developers guide, and some hints on books here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114287/good-book-for-beginning-android-development

Comment: "doing the ui in java just seemed more appealing than xml". After doing Android development for 2 years I strongly oppose this notion. You will have to allocate all of your objects in your code as well as setting up various attributes. You are taking away UI builder, ability to visually tweak the attributes, ability to use Android tools to analyze (and simplify) your layouts.

Comment: It seemed more appealing to me at first, too (coming from Swing experience), but trust me, you want to take advantage of XML layouts. Bite the bullet. Get comfortable with it. Don't work against the platform.

Answer (score 0):

The lack of guides in this matter is simple: Android UI is designed around XML layouts. Building your UI with XML is far more superior to building it programmatically (please refer to my comment to your post for some of the reasons). Adding and tweaking some UI components in the code is common but should not replace but rather supplement the XML-based UI.
You may also consider defining reusable components in XML and then to use `Activity#getLayoutInflater` to "inflate" these snippets. For example that's how items in the list are frequently build. And of course nothing stops you from building your layouts and components entirely within your code. Good practice there would be to create these once in the `Activity#onCreate` and then reuse throughout the rest of the code